# Basic of Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

```
@implementation GroupedInexedViewController
{
    NSDictionary *names;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertyList"
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    names = dict;
    [dict release];
}
```

Is deallocating 'dict' affects 'names'? I mean does it deallocate 'names' too? I saw in another post that its a bad practice? But why?

Edit: ARC is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, if you are not using ARC, yes: deallocating `dict` will affect `names`. This is because you are assigning the `names` pointer to the single `NSDictionary` you have allocated.

If you wanted to have `names` retain the `NSDictionary` when you dealloc `dict`, you would need to send `dict` a `retain` message:

```
names = [dict retain];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're manually calling release, I'm going to assume you're not using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).

There is some terminology mix up here.

It doesn't deallocate `names`. You're decrementing the reference count of `dict` when you call release. Once that reference count hits 0, the memory will be deallocated.

The problem is you assigned `dict` to `names` without first calling `retain` on `dict`.

Retaining an object increases it's reference count.

You can either choose to make `*names` a property, which will handle the memory management for you, or you can manually increment the reference count by calling retain: `names = [dict retain];`

If you do this, you must also implement a `dealloc` method and `release` `names` inside the dealloc method.

Comment: If I have created the 'names' in .h file like this @property(retain,nonatomic) NSDictionary *names;  then will it work? Or do I have to do [dict retain] when I assign?

Comment: @kalkin you're confusing properties and instance variables (once again). `dict` is an instance variable, it does nothing special than holding a value. `self.dict`, however, is an isntance variable, which can be asked to retain its underlying instance variable when set.

Comment: @H2CO3: Actually if I understand @kalkin's question properly, declaring the property in `.h` as a `@property` with retain attributes, and properly synthesizing it in the implementation file, then yes calling `self.names = dict` will retain the value.

Comment: @Alan I wrote nothing different. `self.names = dict;` retains, `names = dict;` does not, but see my answer as well for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Your answer clarifies things somewhat, but in your comment you switched `self.names` with `self.dict` which is confusing.

Comment: @Alan at least it confuses you.

Comment: THanks alan it was exactly what I was asking. I am a newbie thats why didnt understand H2CO3's explanation sorry. Thanks H2CO3.

Comment: It confused me too H2CO3. But as I said I am a newbie I thought you were right!

Answer (score 1):

Your code assigns `names` with the value of `dict`. `dict` is a pointer to an object, so when you assign its value to another pointer (`names`), both pointers are referencing the same object and can be considered identical.

So yes, when you release `dict`, you are also releasing `names`.

BTW, you can assign to `names` directly without going through `dict`:

```
names = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

And if you can enable ARC, you never need to worry about releasing objects.

Answer (score 1):

No answer so far seems to mention the difference between ARC and non-ARC (MRC) usage **and** the difference between properties and instance variables.

First of all, properties are really just setter and getter methods backed by an instance variable. When you set a property like `self.dict = someObject;` and the property was declared as `strong` or `retain`, then `someObject` is retained.

However, if you only have an instance variable (not a property) and you're using MRC, then merely writing `dict = someObject;` duplicates the pointer only but does not increase the reference count - if you write `[someObject release]` after this, you should assume that `dict` is invalidated as well (even if the object pointed to by these two pointers is not actually deallocated - this is a rule of reference counting).

If you are using ARC, then assigning to a variable increases the reference count by one as well - so if `someObject` has a reference count of 1, then writing `dict = someObject;` will increase the reference count of the object (now pointed to *both* by `dict` and `someObject`) to 2.

Comment: @Alan And God save a beginner from using ARC! But if he later wants to move on, let he have a reference. Is it bad that I explained something more than what he asked for?

Comment: Certainly not bad. Memory is a hairy topic in Objective-C that most developers will struggle with at first. ARC makes it better, but at the same time makes things more confusing (one answer mentions that with ARC you never have to release an object--which isn't true at all).

Comment: "ARC makes it better, but at the same time makes things more confusing" - Definitely (+1 for that). Generally that's why I even consider MRC better (but many disagree - the "more confusing" term still holds.)

Comment: Thanks the explanation was very helpful H2C03. I shall keep using MRC because I want to understand the basic :)

Answer (score 0):

dict and names are two different variables, do not mix them!!!

"release" only when you alloc, copy, mutablecopy, retain.
Otherwise if gets created in autorelease mode.

And if you are using ARC, then no need of "release" compiler will take care of all these newly allocated spaces.