# What is the basic input and output when using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to C programming, specifically Objective-C. I am doing a presentation about Objective-C but I am a bit confused about the input and output used in Objective-C. Can anyone tell me the basic input and output for Objective-C?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic of Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392669/basic-of-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

ObjC is by far most often used in the context of iOS and Mac applications. Those applications have graphical user interfaces for essentially all forms of input and output (buttons, text fields, etc etc etc). You would use the event-driven `UIKit` or `AppKit` Cocoa frameworks to do all of that.

ObjC on the mac *can* be (and sometimes is!) used as the language for creating console applications (ie, programs you run via the Terminal command-line app) which use procedural program structure and standard keyboard text input and text output at the console. In this case, you'd typically use the same mechanisms as a C program would-- `printf` and `scanf` and all of their cousins-- to get input via the standard input stream and produce text on the standard output stream.

Comment: Is it ok if you can use an example of code which use printf and scanf? Also, you mentioned their "cousins", can you also use those in the example as well?

Comment: This is basic C programming so you can find examples and tutorials all over the place. Here is just the first result from a web search: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-input-output

Comment: You are very unlikely to use `printf` and `scanf` in an iOS app. @FahadKhan Please update your question with a better description of what you are trying to ask. It's very unclear which is why your question is getting so many down-votes.

Comment: @BenZotto The OP approved that edit to add the iOS tag.

Comment: @rmaddy ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯